# Filter nested array values (remove the ones that dont match both groups and children) pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

How to filter out nested children and groups, so in the below example if i searched for "Nest Name 3" then only Group B would be returned and only Nested Name 3.

I have an arrary like this:

```
items = [
    {
        "key": "Group A",
        "value": [
            {
              "name": "Nest Name 1"
            }
    },
    {
        "key": "Group B",
        "value": [
            {
              "name": "Nest Name 2"
            },
            {
              "name": "Nest Name 3"
            }
                 [
    }
]
```

And in an angular pipe i am trying to return (in the same format) groups where the nested name matches a string. So in this case  if i searched for 2 then only Group b should be brought back and only the first nested object would be brought back.

I have my match working on none nested code:
`items?.filter(item => searchText.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp(q, 'i').test(item[field]))`

searchText is the word i am searching for and field is the name of the field in this case name.

I thought something like this would work:

```
var tempList = [];
    items.filter(group => group.value.filter(item => searchText.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp(q, 'i').test(item[field])))).forEach(product => tempList.push(product));
    return tempList;
```

but while it brings back the correct groups the actual nested items are not removed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search through your `items`, you need to compare the name of each `item.value` against your `searchText` string also inside each `group.value`. Here's the code to do so:

```
const filterItems = (searchText: string): Group[] => {
  return items
    .filter((item) =>
      item.value.some((value) => isSearchValue(value, searchText))
    )
    .map((group) => {
      return {
        key: group.key,
        value: group.value.filter((value) =>
          isSearchValue(value, searchText)
        ),
      };
    });
};
```

> The `some()` method was used to iterate through the array of values.
> This method returns `true` if at least one element in the array
> satisfies the provided testing function.
>
> [Documentation for the some method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

The function `isSearchValue` can be like this:

```
const isSearchValue = (value:ItemValue,searchText:string):boolean=>{
  return value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
}
```

Where there are the following types and interfaces:

```
type ItemValue = {name:string};
interface Group{
  key:string;
  value:ItemValue[];
}
```

To give you a better idea of what's happening, I've created a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ngsz4j?file=index.ts) with an input search feature.

Comment: Thanks but this just does what my other ones does, it filters the main groups and brings back all children, i wanted to filter the main groups and also remove any children that dont match the searchText.

Comment: This seems to work, first filter the groups by the children then overwrite the value with the children also filtered:
```
 return items.filter((item) => item.value.some((value) => searchText.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp(q, 'i').test(value[field]))))
      .map(p => ({
        ...p,
        value: p.value.filter(child => searchText.split(' ').every(q => new RegExp(q, 'i').test(child[field])))
      }));
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be working. Could you provide more context on what the `field` property is used for? I've run tests on the code I provided you and it appears to be working as expected. To give you a better idea of what's happening, I've created a StackBlitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ngsz4j?file=index.ts) with an input search feature. 

Anyway, If you want to obtain a new array after using the filter function, you'll need to assign its result to a new variable, like this: `const filteredItems = filterItems(searchText)`.

Comment: I think its my fault for not explaining what I needed better, your code works fine for filtering the groups but it doesnt filter out the children (value).

So on your stackblitz example if you type in name 3 it brings back:

[{"key":"Group B","value":[{"name":"Nest Name 2"},{"name":"Nest Name 3"}]}]

I wanted it to bring back:

[{"key":"Group B","value":[{"name":"Nest Name 3"}]}]

Field in this case is name, i just made it like that so i could pass in the name of the field i was looking for (so i could reuse it for other things). Thanks

Comment: I've made some revisions to the reply and the Stackblitz demo. Please let me know if anything remains unclear. Additionally, updating the text of your question could be helpful for others who may encounter a similar issue and struggle to understand from just reading the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks alot, the new example works perfectly, i appreciate it and i have updated the question to better reflect what i was after.